# VIsual Studio 2010. Load testing. How to assign different tests to different virtual users?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I have a small load testing here and I'm curious how can I set different web perfomance tests to different virtual users. I'd like to make something like this:

Test A: 3 users;

Test B: 20 users;

Test C: 30 uers;

TEst D: 50 users;

And I'd like all that to go at the same time. Is there a way to do that? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot actually give constant values to the virtual users but you can define their percentage distribution.

1. Create a new Load Test.
2. In the `New Load Test Wizard` click on the `Load Pattern` tab, select `Constant Load` and set the `Users Count` number (e.g. 100).
3. In the `Test Mix Model` select the `Based on the number of virtual users` option.
4. In the `Test Mix` tab, add your tests and set the `Distribution` of your tests:

   - TestA:   3% -->  3 users
   - TestB:  19% --> 19 users
   - TestC:  29% --> 29 users
   - TestD:  49% --> 49 users

You can also set the percentages manually but if you try to set them like this:

- TestA: 3%
- TestB: 20%
- TestC: 30%
- TestD: 50%

then each value will be prorated to 100%. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243157.aspx) for more details.